# NestJS Mongoose - CannotDetermineTypeError: Cannot determine a type

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

after updating my NestJS Mongoose libraries to the following versions, an error keeps preventing my NestJS application from starting:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^7.6.18",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.6.18",
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.4",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.18",
"dotenv": "^8.6.0",
"firebase-admin": "^9.11.0",
"mongoose": "^5.13.6",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rimraf": "^3.0.2",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7"
```

My code:

```
@Schema()
export class ExerciseQuestion extends Document {
    @Prop()
    question: any;

    @Prop()
    solution: any;

    @Optional()
    @Prop()
    options: any[];

    @Prop()
    solutionString: string;

    @Prop()
    type: string;

    @Prop()
    difficulty: number;

    @Prop()
    tags: string[];

    @Prop()
    hint: string;
}
```

This is the complete error message that I get, when I use `nest start`:

```
D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\decorators\prop.decorator.js:22
                throw new errors_1.CannotDetermineTypeError((_a = target.constructor) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.name, propertyKey);
                ^

CannotDetermineTypeError: Cannot determine a type for the "ExerciseQuestion.question" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })" decorator.
    at D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\decorators\prop.decorator.js:22:23
    at DecorateProperty (D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:553:33)
    at Object.decorate (D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:123:24)
    at __decorate (D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\dist\exercise\schemas\exercise.schema.js:4:92)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\dist\exercise\schemas\exercise.schema.js:49:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Bibliothek\Dokumente\myapp\myapp_api\dist\exercise\exercise.service.js:16:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
```

Why is this happening and is there any solution to this?

When I try to define the type in the @Prop decorator, a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error keeps coming.

I'd be very thankful for any advice on this!

Comment: What _should_ the types for `question` and `solution` be?

Comment: Both variables can have different types, because of this I'm using the any type. Until updating the packages, there weren't any problems.

Comment: It would help to know what you updated from.

Comment: I updated from these packages:
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4"

Comment: @MrMik did you found a solution for this issue?